# How to merge repeated columns to get multiple lines instead of multiple columns or comma-separated data into a single cell?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dataframe

I'm scraping data from a javascript environment and want to get as output a preset of columns that have multiple lines filled with the values that I get from data scraping. How to correlate a value found to a predefined column or how to merge columns with the same name to multiple lines data?

The data I'm scraping is a Justice Court decisions' database, which is public.

I've researched how to merge columns in Pandas DataFrame, but the best output so far was to merge them and get a comma-separated data, which is useless to me aiming the purpose of my scraping.

MWE:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from openpyxl import Workbook
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

url = "https://scon.stj.jus.br/SCON/legaplic/toc.jsp?materia=%27Lei+8.429%2F1992+%28Lei+DE+IMPROBIDADE+ADMINISTRATIVA%29%27.mat.&b=TEMA&p=true&t=&l=1&i=18&ordem=MAT,@NUM"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[16]/a')
python_button.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/span[2]/a')
python_button.click()

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])

textList = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTexto")

resultados = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

parse = resultados.find('div', {'id':'listadocumentos'})
paragrafoBRS = parse.find_all('div',{'class':'paragrafoBRS'})

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/a[2]')
python_button.click()

textList2 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTexto")

resultados2 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

parse = resultados2.find('div', {'id':'listadocumentos'})
paragrafoBRS2 = parse.find_all('div',{'class':'paragrafoBRS'})

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/a[4]')
python_button.click()

textList3 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTexto")

resultados3 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

parse = resultados3.find('div', {'id':'listadocumentos'})
paragrafoBRS3 = parse.find_all('div',{'class':'paragrafoBRS'})

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/a[4]')
python_button.click()

textList4 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTexto")

resultados4 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

parse = resultados4.find('div', {'id':'listadocumentos'})
paragrafoBRS4 = parse.find_all('div',{'class':'paragrafoBRS'})

python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/form/div/a[4]')
python_button.click()

textList5 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("docTexto")

resultados5 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')

parse = resultados5.find('div', {'id':'listadocumentos'})
paragrafoBRS5 = parse.find_all('div',{'class':'paragrafoBRS'})

header = []
content = []
for each in paragrafoBRS:
    header.append(each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip())
    content.append(each.find(['div','pre'], {'class':'docTexto'}).text.strip())

for each in paragrafoBRS2:
    header.append(each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip())
    content.append(each.find(['div','pre'], {'class':'docTexto'}).text.strip())

for each in paragrafoBRS3:
    header.append(each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip())
    content.append(each.find(['div','pre'], {'class':'docTexto'}).text.strip())

for each in paragrafoBRS4:
    header.append(each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip())
    content.append(each.find(['div','pre'], {'class':'docTexto'}).text.strip())

for each in paragrafoBRS5:
    header.append(each.find('h4', {'class':'docTitulo'}).text.strip())
    content.append(each.find(['div','pre'], {'class':'docTexto'}).text.strip())

    df = pd.DataFrame([content], columns = header)

df.to_excel('dados.xlsx')

driver.quit()
```

I expect to scrape the data to an Excel DataFrame which have the following columns:

- Processo
- Relator(a)
- Órgão Julgador
- Data do Julgamento
- Data da Publicação/Fonte
- Ementa
- Acórdão
- Informações Complementares à Ementa (ICE)
- Referência Legislativa
- Jurisprudência Citada
- Acórdãos Similares

Each line will represent a document from the decisions' database obtained from the javascript environment.

When I get to this output, I also expect that I get the cells filled with the correlated column and when there is no data for the column, get a NaN result, preserving the document line.

The actual output is an Excel DataFrame with 391 columns, instead of 11, and 1 line of data, repeating the columns above 41 times.

The code below demonstrates the information regarding Document 1, as you can see by h3 id "DOC1".

I want each DOC to match a line.

As you can also see, docTitulo corresponds to the column name and docTexto corresponds to the contents of the row.

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
<h3><a href="javascript:;" id="DOC1">Documento 1</a></h3>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo">Processo</h4>
<div class="docTexto">
AgInt no AREsp 739451 / RJ<br>AGRAVO INTERNO NO AGRAVO EM RECURSO ESPECIAL<br>2015/0161439-6
</div>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo">Relator(a)</h4>
<pre class="docTexto">Ministro BENEDITO GONÇALVES (1142)</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo">Órgão Julgador</h4>
<pre class="docTexto">T1 - PRIMEIRA TURMA</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo">Data do Julgamento</h4>
<pre class="docTexto">26/02/2019</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo">Data da Publicação/Fonte</h4>
<pre class="docTexto">DJe 26/03/2019</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<a name="EMEN"></a>
<h4 class="docTitulo">Ementa</h4>
<pre class="docTexto">PROCESSO  CIVIL.  AGRAVO  INTERNO  NO  AGRAVO  EM  RECURSO ESPECIAL.
VIOLAÇÃO  DO  ART. 535 DO CPC/1973. AUSÊNCIA DE ARGUMENTAÇÃO. SÚMULA
284/STF.  DEFICIÊNCIA  NA ARGUMENTAÇÃO RECURSAL.SÚMULA 284/STF. AÇÃO
CIVIL  PÚBLICA POR ATO DE IMPROBIDADE ADMINISTRATIVA. RECEBIMENTO DA
PETIÇÃO  INICIAL.  ANÁLISE  DO  ELEMENTO  SUBJETIVO.  NECESSIDADE DE
INSTRUÇÃO  PROCESSUAL.  PRESENÇA  DE  INDÍCIOS DE ATO DE IMPROBIDADE
ADMINISTRATIVA  EXPRESSAMENTE  RECONHECIDOS PELO TRIBUNAL DE ORIGEM.
REEXAME DE MATÉRIA FÁTICO PROBATÓRIA. IMPOSSIBILIDADE. SÚMULA 7/STJ.
1. O recurso não demonstra, com transparência e precisão, qual seria
o  ponto  omisso, contraditório ou obscuro do acórdão recorrido, não
se conhecendo da alegada violação do art. 535 do CPC/1973.
Incidência, por analogia, do entendimento da Súmula 284/STF.
2.  Aplica-se  a  Súmula 284/STF quanto à alegada violação dos arts.
9º,  10, 11 e 17, § 6º, da Lei nº 8.429/1992, tendo em vista que não
desenvolveu a parte agravante argumentos para demonstrar de que modo
tais dispositivos foram ofendidos.
3.  O  indeferimento da petição inicial da ação civil de improbidade
administrativa somente é cabível nos casos que o magistrado entender
inexistente  o  suposto ato de improbidade, da improcedência da ação
ou  a  inadequação da via eleita, hipóteses não configuradas no caso
concreto.
4.  Rever o entendimento do acórdão recorrido ensejaria o reexame do
conjunto fático-probatório da demanda, providência vedada em sede de
recurso especial, ante a Súmula 7/STJ.
5. Agravo interno não provido.</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo">Acórdão</h4>
<pre class="docTexto">Vistos,  relatados  e discutidos os autos em que são partes as acima
indicadas,  acordam  os  Ministros  da  Primeira  Turma  do Superior
Tribunal  de Justiça prosseguindo o julgamento, por maioria, vencido
o Sr. Ministro Napoleão Nunes Maia Filho, negar provimento ao agravo
interno,  nos  termos do voto-vista do Sr. Ministro Relator. Os Srs.
Ministros  Sérgio  Kukina, Regina Helena Costa (Presidente) e Gurgel
de Faria votaram com o Sr. Ministro Relator.</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">

<h4 class="docTitulo" onmouseover="mostra_help('Indexacao1')" onmouseout="esconde_help('Indexacao1');" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">Informações Complementares à Ementa (ICE)</h4>
<div id="helpIndexacao1" class="helpbox" style="display: none">

<object data="/docs_internet/jurisprudencia/ajuda/TextoInformacoesAdicionais.htm" class="tpin6"></object>

</div>

<pre class="docTexto">     "A conclusão alcançada pela Corte a quo está em consonância com
a orientação deste Tribunal Superior sobre o tema, a qual autoriza o
recebimento   da  petição  inicial  da  ação  civil  de  improbidade
administrativa,  na  hipótese da presença de indícios de cometimento
de  atos  enquadrados  na  Lei  de  Improbidade  Administrativa. Com
efeito, na fase inicial prevista no art. 17 e §§ 7º, 8º e 9º, da Lei
nº  8.429/1992,  vigora o princípio do in dubio pro societate, a fim
de possibilitar o maior resguardo do interesse público".
     "[...],  deve  ser considerada prematura a extinção do processo
com  julgamento  de  mérito,  tendo em vista não existirem elementos
fáticos ou probatório suficientes para um juízo conclusivo acerca da
demanda, tampouco quanto a efetiva presença do elemento subjetivo do
suposto ato de improbidade administrativa, o qual exige, em regra, a
regular instrução processual".
     (VOTO VENCIDO) (MIN. NAPOLEÃO NUNES MAIA FILHO)
     "Verdadeiramente, é preciso que o libelo acusatório, assim como
as  decisões  judiciais  que  venham  a permitir o trâmite das ações
sancionadoras,  apontem com precisão os indícios mínimos da autoria,
cumplicidade,  participação,  ainda  que de somenos importância. Daí
porque   a   expressão   in  dubio  pro  societate,  cuja  origem  é
desconhecida,  deveria  ser  banida  das decisões que tratam da fase
inaugural  das  ações  de  improbidade, por nada dizer a respeito da
potencial autoria do fato que se repute ímprobo".</pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo"
    onmouseover="mostra_help('ReferenciasLegislativas1')"
    onmouseout="esconde_help('ReferenciasLegislativas1');"
    style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">Referência Legislativa</h4>
<div id="helpReferenciasLegislativas1" class="helpbox" style="display: none">
    <object data="/docs_internet/jurisprudencia/ajuda/TextoReferenciasLegislativas.htm" class="helpReferenciasLegislativas"></object>
</div>
<pre class="docTexto"><a target="_blank" href="/SCON/include/linkPlanalto.jsp?tipo=LEI&numero=005869&ano=1973">LEG:FED <span class="tooltip">LEI<span class="tooltiptext">LEI ORDINÁRIA</span></span>:005869 ANO:1973</a><br>*****  CPC-73      CÓDIGO DE PROCESSO CIVIL DE 1973<br>        ART:00535<br><br>LEG:FED <span class="tooltip">SUM<span class="tooltiptext">SÚMULA</span></span>:****** ANO:****<br>*****  SUM(STF)    SÚMULA DO SUPREMO TRIBUNAL FEDERAL<br>        SUM:000284<br><br><a target="_blank" href="/SCON/include/linkPlanalto.jsp?tipo=LEI&numero=008429&ano=1992">LEG:FED <span class=highlightBrs>LEI:008429</span> ANO:1992</a><br>*****  LIA-92      <span class=highlightBrs>LEI DE IMPROBIDADE</span> ADMINISTRATIVA<br>        ART:00009   <span class=highlightBrs>ART:00010   ART:00011   ART:00017   PAR:00006</span><br>        PAR:00007   PAR:00008   PAR:00009<br><br>LEG:FED <span class="tooltip">SUM<span class="tooltiptext">SÚMULA</span></span>:****** ANO:****<br>*****  SUM(STJ)    SÚMULA DO SUPERIOR TRIBUNAL DE JUSTIÇA<br>        <a href="javascript:AbrirDocumento('/SCON/sumanot/toc.jsp?livre=(sumula+adj+7).sub.','SU');" >SUM:000007</a></pre>
</div>

<div class="paragrafoBRS">
<h4 class="docTitulo" onmouseover="mostra_help('Veja1')"
    onmouseout="esconde_help('Veja1');" style="cursor: pointer; text-decoration: underline;">Jurisprudência Citada</h4>
<div id="helpVeja1" class="helpbox" style="display: none">
    <object data="/docs_internet/jurisprudencia/ajuda/TextoVeja.htm" class="helpVeja"></object>
</div>

<pre class="docTexto">(PROCESSUAL CIVIL - AÇÃO DE IMPROBIDADE ADMINISTRATIVA -<br>INDEFERIMENTO DA PETIÇÃO INICIAL - HIPÓTESES)<br>     STJ - <a href="/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?i=1&b=ACOR&livre=(('AINTARESP'.clas.+e+@num='910840')+ou+('AGINT NO ARESP'+adj+'910840'.suce.))&thesaurus=JURIDICO&fr=veja" class="">AgInt no AREsp 910840</a>-RN, <a href="/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?i=1&b=ACOR&livre=(('RESP'.clap.+e+@num='1192758')+ou+('RESP'+adj+'1192758'.suce.))&thesaurus=JURIDICO&fr=veja" class="">REsp 1192758</a>-MG<br>(PROCESSUAL CIVIL - AÇÃO DE IMPROBIDADE ADMINISTRATIVA - PREMATURA<br>EXTINÇÃO DO PROCESSO COM JULGAMENTO DE MÉRITO - NECESSIDADE DA<br>INSTRUÇÃO PROCESSUAL)<br>     STJ - <a href="/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?i=1&b=ACOR&livre=(('AIEDARESP'.clas.+e+@num='925670')+ou+('AGINT NOS EDCL NO ARESP'+adj+'925670'.suce.))&thesaurus=JURIDICO&fr=veja" class="">AgInt nos EDcl no AREsp 925670</a>-MG,<br>           <a href="/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?i=1&b=ACOR&livre=(('AGARESP'.clas.+e+@num='400779')+ou+('AGRG NO ARESP'+adj+'400779'.suce.))&thesaurus=JURIDICO&fr=veja" class="">AgRg no AREsp 400779</a>-ES<br>(PROCESSUAL CIVIL - AÇÃO DE IMPROBIDADE ADMINISTRATIVA - PRESENÇA DE<br>INDÍCIOS DE PRÁTICA DE ATO DE IMPROBIDADE - REEXAME DE PROVA)<br>     STJ - <a href="/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?i=1&b=ACOR&livre=(('AGARESP'.clas.+e+@num='706071')+ou+('AGRG NO ARESP'+adj+'706071'.suce.))&thesaurus=JURIDICO&fr=veja" class="">AgRg no AREsp 706071</a>-SP, <a href="/SCON/jurisprudencia/toc.jsp?i=1&b=ACOR&livre=(('AGRESP'.clas.+e+@num='1281089')+ou+('AGRG NO RESP'+adj+'1281089'.suce.))&thesaurus=JURIDICO&fr=veja" class="">AgRg no REsp 1281089</a>-MG</pre>
</div>

</div>

<hr>
```

Comment: Unless you post some sort of HTML along with this, it will be very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: @GregBurghardt you're right. I've edited the post to include the HTML source.

Comment: Can you explain why is comma separated values are useless to you?  (csv can very easily be converted to excel file...)

Comment: The values got comma-separated inside the xlsx file. I know that I can convert the CSV file, but considering that my values got lots of commas, I don’t know if it is productive.